# Accessing MSMQ Local System Dead-letter queue - gives "Computer specified cannot be found"

Tags: windows-7, msmq

Is there some add'l setup I need to do in order to access this queue or any other Queue under the System Queues folder?

This is on Windows 7 Pro, as Admin, with MSMQ installed.

It says the "The list of messages can't be retrieved. Error: Computer specified cannot be found"

I'm logged in as a local Admin and I can get to other private queues just fine.
I'd plan to use it to see the failure messages from other queues.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the core of that error is that it is looking up the computer name in active directory (I would assume that you are not hooked up to a domain with MSMQ AD Integration configured).... I get that error even on a Windows Server Dev box connected to an AD domain because the integration is not set up (I don't need it).

It is one reason I ended up developing this tool...

http://viridissoftware.com.au/Products/MSMQInspector/

Email me and I will drop you a license if you want...

PK :-)